# Choosing between superglobals for navigation in admin section

Tags: php, navigation, admin, query-string, superglobals

I'm creating a custom admin page that will enable the client to navigate the content list and edit/delete/add items to and from database(myPhpAdmin) in PHP and I was wondering about the correct way to do it.

For the front-end part (non-admin pages) I used links to store variables in URL and then retrieve it using the `$_GET` superglobal, example: `http://localhost/myWebsite/pages/products.php?***main_id=1***`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['main_id'])) {
    $mainID = $_GET['main_id'];
    getSubGroupsWithMainID($mainID);
}
?>
```

Now, I'm not really sure that should be visible in the admin section (or should it?), so my idea was to use the `$_POST` superglobal in a similar manner to retrieve the necessary query parameters. My only concern is that links or `<a>` tags can't really send the data into the `$_POST`.

I hope I was clear enough with the explanation of the problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: POST and GET are really just as insecure as each other. Both are visible to anyone with some basic knowledge of how the web works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a very general question (almost opinion-based), but if I understand you correctly, this is my advice:

If loading a script that is READing from the database, use `$_GET`.
If you want to incorporate permissions with regard to certain pages, you can associate your users' privileges with the page ids.

If loading a script that runs a CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE query, use `$_POST`.

p.s. There is no benefit in declaring `$mainID`. Just write `getSubGroupsWithMainID($_GET['main_id']);` inside of the `if` block.

Comment: Noted, well i'm still new to PHP... and that was the example for the front-end page, which I have no problem with. My question was related to admin page of the site and the navigation within the admin page. Client should click on the desired branch before the items are manifested. Should I use the same method? Is it a possible security risk to use POST on a sensitive part of the application (admin page)?  Normally I would do this with links/ a tags. I just wanted to hear an opinion from someone experienced than I on the matter..

Comment: Yes, my advice remains unchanged.  As my pal, Riggs, has stated, there is no sufficient security improvement from choosing `$_GET` versus `$_POST`.  You will still need to be just as careful with your codes.  The reason that you wouldn't want to use `$_GET` for `CREATE`|`UPDATE`|`DELETE` processes is because robots/crawlers may chase your urls and "set off" queries that you don't want to be "set off" ...then again, those types of processes should normally be behind password protection.

Comment: Well I did put the password on the admin page with Salt encryption. This question was kinda related to adding a security layer and the general practice on how it's done. Appreciate the prompt reply guys!